# Sublime text: Get full yaml tree path by clicking on a node and search for full tree path

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Let's say I have a .yml file with thousands of entries, e.g.

```
en:
  something:
    1000 entries
  something_else:
    foo:
      bar:
        2000 entries
  stuff:
    i_am:
      looking:
        500 entries
      for: "hello"
```

Now, let's say I found `for: "hello"`. Is there an easy way to get the full path, meaning `something.stuff.i_am.looking.for` without looking up every tree node?

And my second question - given a full path, how can I search in sublime for it? Let's say I have hundreds of yml-files, how can I search for path `something.stuff.i_am.looking.for`? Searching for one of the keys is quite ineffective.

Comment: sounds like you would benefit from installing a plugin like https://packagecontrol.io/packages/YAML%20Nav

Comment: @KeithHall that looks awesome, thanks! The only feature right now, that I'm missing is the **global** search within a tree path (second question). Do you know any possibility to search for a yaml-path or maybe a package for that?

Answer (score 0):

[Keith Halls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall) answer is the right one.

Install [YAML Nav plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137327/sublime-text-get-full-yaml-tree-path-by-clicking-on-a-node-and-search-for-full) and then when on target node, click `Command+Shift+W (Control+Shift+W)` in YAML source to copy YAML path to clipboard.

Comment: If only this would work with ST 4 (build 4143 to be precise). It doesn't seem to.... 